# Ошибка при получение md5 хеша сигнатуры

Tags: android, c++, jni

При попытке скомпилировать код вылазят две ошибки :

```
cannot initialize a parameter of type  'jarray' (aka '_jarray *') with an lvalue of type 'jobject' (aka '_jobject *')
```

```
cannot initialize a parameter of type  'jbyteArray' (aka '_jbyteArray *') with an lvalue of type 'jobject' (aka '_jobject *')
```

Мой код:

```
const char *getSignatures(JNIEnv *env, jobject context) {
    jclass versionClass = env->FindClass( "android/os/Build$VERSION");
    jfieldID sdkIntFieldID = env->GetStaticFieldID( versionClass, "SDK_INT", "I");
    int sdkInt = env->GetStaticIntField( versionClass, sdkIntFieldID);
    // Context
    jclass contextClass = env->FindClass("android/content/Context");
    // Context#getPackageManager()
    jmethodID pmMethod = env->GetMethodID(contextClass, "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
    jobject pm = env->CallObjectMethod( context, pmMethod);
    jclass pmClass = env->GetObjectClass( pm);
    // PackageManager#getPackageInfo()
    jmethodID piMethod = env->GetMethodID( pmClass, "getPackageInfo", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");
    // Context#getPackageName()
    jmethodID pnMethod = env->GetMethodID( contextClass, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring packageName = (jstring) (env->CallObjectMethod( context, pnMethod));
    int flags;
    if (sdkInt >= 28) {
        flags = 0x08000000; // PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES
    } else {
        flags = 0x00000040; // PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES
    }
    jobject packageInfo = env->CallObjectMethod(pm, piMethod, packageName, flags);
    jclass piClass = env->GetObjectClass( packageInfo);
    // PackageInfo#signingInfo.apkContentsSigners | PackageInfo#signatures
    jobjectArray signatures;
    if (sdkInt >= 28) {
        // PackageInfo#signingInfo
        jfieldID signingInfoField = env->GetFieldID( piClass, "signingInfo", "Landroid/content/pm/SigningInfo;");
        jobject signingInfoObject = env->GetObjectField( packageInfo, signingInfoField);
        jclass signingInfoClass = env->GetObjectClass(signingInfoObject);
        // SigningInfo#apkContentsSigners
        jmethodID signaturesMethod = env->GetMethodID(signingInfoClass, "getApkContentsSigners", "()[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;");
        jobject signaturesObject = env->CallObjectMethod(signingInfoObject, signaturesMethod);
        signatures = (jobjectArray) (signaturesObject);
    } else {
        // PackageInfo#signatures
        jfieldID signaturesField = env->GetFieldID( piClass, "signatures", "[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;");
        jobject signaturesObject = env->GetObjectField( packageInfo, signaturesField);
        if (env->IsSameObject( signaturesObject, NULL)) {
           // return ""; // in case signatures is null
        }
        signatures = (jobjectArray) (signaturesObject);
    }
    // Signature[0]
    jobject firstSignature = env->GetObjectArrayElement(signatures, 0);
    jclass signatureClass = env->GetObjectClass( firstSignature);
    // PackageInfo#signatures[0].toCharString()
    jmethodID signatureByteMethod = env->GetMethodID( signatureClass, "toByteArray", "()[B");
    jobject signatureByteArray = (jobject) env->CallObjectMethod(firstSignature, signatureByteMethod);
    // MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    jclass mdClass = env->FindClass("java/security/MessageDigest");
    jmethodID mdMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID( mdClass, "getInstance", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/security/MessageDigest;");
    jobject md5Object = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(mdClass, mdMethod, env->NewStringUTF( "MD5"));
    // MessageDigest#update
    jmethodID mdUpdateMethod = env->GetMethodID( mdClass, "update", "([B)V");// The return value of this function is void, write V
    env->CallVoidMethod(md5Object, mdUpdateMethod, signatureByteArray);
    // MessageDigest#digest
    jmethodID mdDigestMethod = env->GetMethodID( mdClass, "digest", "()[B");
    jobject fingerPrintByteArray = env->CallObjectMethod(md5Object, mdDigestMethod);
    // iterate over the bytes and convert to md5 array
// Ошибки
    jsize byteArrayLength = env->GetArrayLength(fingerPrintByteArray);
    jbyte *fingerPrintByteArrayElements = env->GetByteArrayElements(fingerPrintByteArray, JNI_FALSE);
// Ошибки
    char *charArray = (char *) fingerPrintByteArrayElements;
    char *md5 = (char *) calloc(2 * byteArrayLength + 1, sizeof(char));
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < byteArrayLength; k++) {
        sprintf(&md5[2 * k], "%02X", charArray[k]); // Not sure if the cast is needed
    }
    return md5;
}
```

Comment: Вы хоть пометьте комментами строки, на которые указывают ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jobject fingerPrintByteArray = env->CallObjectMethod(md5Object, mdDigestMethod);`
**=>**
`jbyteArray fingerPrintByteArray = (jbyteArray) env->CallObjectMethod(md5Object, mdDigestMethod);`